# Crm outlook client and ribbon scripts

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

i have a weird problem inside the outlook client. I'm using a script rule to enable/disable a custom ribbon button. The problem is that on the on-load of the form, everything works correctly, if i change the section and i look at the related contacts, for example from the account form, the script crashes, the and the ribbon becomes unusable.

Now I don't know exactly what is going on, looks like the ribbon is executed and the scripts are going crazy. Also, I'm using a soap call, that is triggered by that button, but that is throwing an error as soon as you try to execute it.

Anyone else had the same problem? How can i read form fields to enable/disable the ribbon button?

Comment: Are you using the ribbon workbench for this? (http://www.develop1.net/public/Download%20Ribbon%20Workbench.aspx)  If so then I would be happy to walk you through the method to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having trouble importing new solutions on the dev machine, so i wasn't able to import ribbon workbench. I tried to follow this tutorial: http://www.develop1.net/public/post/Make-sure-ribbon-buttons-appear-in-Outlook.aspx but when i export the solution and try to add a display rule

```
<DisplayRules >
    <CrmClientTypeRule Type="Web" />
</DisplayRules>
```

I can't import back the solution, even if the xml should have been correct. I decided to try a different approach, I'm now trying to use Xrm.Page.context.isOutlookClient() to enable the button, but I'm still not sure that after changing tab the "namespace" Xrm.Page will be populated.

Comment: I guess this solution worked correctly for me, now the annoying message "report to Microsoft" is not appearing anymore and the ribbon is still usable